# Differential equation (maybe Lagrange equation)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone help me with this equation:

$ 3y+x = (2x+4)y' + 2y'^2 $
I tried to represent it as: $ y = x.f(y') + g(y') $
, substitute p = y' and differentiate ($ d \over dx$). After that I thought if I can prove that $p' > 0 (p' < 0) $ I can use the inverse function of p to reduce the equation to linear equation but I failed.

What should I do and how? A description of the solution would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it is of D'Alambert typ

Answer (score 0):

$3y+x=(2x+4)y'+2y'^2$

$2y'^2+(2x+4)y'-3y-x=0$

Apply the method in http://www.ae.illinois.edu/lndvl/Publications/2002_IJND.pdf#page=2:

Let $F(x,y,t)=2t^2+(2x+4)t-3y-x$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dx}{dt}=-\dfrac{\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial t}}{\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}+t\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y}}=-\dfrac{4t+2x+4}{2t-1+t(-3)}=\dfrac{2x+4t+4}{t+1}=\dfrac{2x}{t+1}+4$

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}-\dfrac{2x}{t+1}=4$

I.F.$=e^{-\int\frac{2}{t+1}dt}=e^{-2\ln(t+1)}=\dfrac{1}{(t+1)^2}$

$\therefore\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(\dfrac{x}{(t+1)^2}\right)=\dfrac{4}{(t+1)^2}$

$\dfrac{x}{(t+1)^2}=\int\dfrac{4}{(t+1)^2}dt$

$\dfrac{x}{(t+1)^2}=-\dfrac{4}{t+1}+C_1$

$x=C_1(t+1)^2-4(t+1)$

$\therefore\dfrac{dy}{dt}=tx=C_1t(t+1)^2-4t(t+1)$

$y=\int(C_1t(t+1)^2-4t(t+1))~dt$

$y=\dfrac{C_1t^4}{4}+\dfrac{2(C_1-2)t^3}{3}+\dfrac{(C_1-4)t^2}{2}+C_2$

Hence $\begin{cases}x=C_1(t+1)^2-4(t+1)\\y=\dfrac{C_1t^4}{4}+\dfrac{2(C_1-2)t^3}{3}+\dfrac{(C_1-4)t^2}{2}+C_2\end{cases}$